# Implementation a cordova application in W8 device

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-8, sencha-touch, internet-explorer-11

I am working with a Cordova application (based in this case in the framework Sencha Touch 2) but I am looking in the implementation to W8 layout is too small.

I have added the next line but the behavior is the same..

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,    maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />
```

Device is based in IE11.

What am I doing wrong?? any clue??

Thank you in advance!